# Find/Replace Date Formats (Long Month Names) Using Regex - and Dropping Times

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I need to convert (find and replace) date formatting on a Wordpress site using Regex (per the plugin I'm using).

Essentially, I need to convert from **F j, Y g:i a** to **Ymd**.

For instance, I need to convert

**February 16, 2018
3:00 PM**

to **20180216** - with no time at all

My endgame is to get the fields to match similar posts for sorting results. I've got a function that will sort results by dates (&start_date=20180201&end_date=20180228). It works perfect for posts I manually created using a datepicker, but not for these formats that are being imported.

Comment: And why exactly can't you use `strtotime()` and `date()`?  Or even better, the `DateTime` object.

Comment: That works on the frontend template for display purposes, but the field value is not actually saving like that. When I output it raw, it's outputting as the original. So, sorting by that key isn't working.

Comment: The plugin I'm using allows you to find and replace values using regex, but I can't find the right code to do so.

Comment: I tried each of these below. 

\w+\s\d{1,2},\s\d{4}\s\d{1,2}:\d{2}\s\w+
<br><br>
/(Jan(uary)?|Feb(ruary)?|Mar(ch)?|Apr(il)?|May|June?|July?|Aug(ust)?|Sep(t(ember)?)?|Oct(ober)?|Nov(ember)?|Dec(ember)?)\s\d{1,2},\s\d{4}\s\d{1,2}:\d{2}\s\w+

Comment: I don't really understand your first comment.  You should include your code in your post or better describe what's actually going on.  It seems to me like you only have a problem because you're choosing to use functions that aren't meant for what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm not explaining it correctly. It's not a coding issue in a template file. I need to convert the imported data before it's actually saved as the value for a custom field (the return value), rather than format its output. The plugin allows me to do so with a Regex, I just don't know Regex enough to understand the proper coding to do so.

Comment: For instance, on another type of import. I got the below to work just fine. <br>Find:
 (T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}-:\d{4}) <br> Replace: $3$2$1 <br> But, the format of that data didn't include the long date (ie. February) or time.

Comment: Honestly, all I can say is find a new plugin or write your own.  What you're using does not meet your needs.

Comment: Can you show us a more accurate depiction of your actual data and code?  Regex really is poorly equipped to perform this task versus date functions.  Let's move this question toward resolution.